# Best practice to store a very small of data for extremely fast and efficient retrieval in php?

Tags: php

I have written an image script that overlays an SVG design on top of a piece of apparel.  The image script will be executed several times per second and must be very fast and efficient.

There are only 25 unique apparel files.

Each of the 25 apparel files has x,y coordinate data values that must be used in the script to properly place the SVG design graphic.

Storing them in Mysql seems like overkill, and connecting to MySQL just to get x,y coordinates on each script execution seems extremely inefficient.

Of course, I could store the values in the script as an array, but this too seems like bad practice.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how my excellent question was too broad?  I will try harder to be more excellent next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use an associated array within a config file.

My coord-config.php config file:

```
$coordinates = array( 

"P001" => array ("design_width" => 375,"dx" => 320,"dy" => 230,),
"P002" => array ("design_width" => 35,"dx" => 35,"dy" => 35,) 

 );
```

How I used in my image script:

```
require "/var/www/html/build/coord-config.php";

$design_width = $coordinates[$product]['design_width'];
$dx = $coordinates[$product]['dx'];
$dy = $coordinates[$product]['dy'];
```

Comment: Great answer user3672303.  You are the best.

Comment: Fantastic advice user3672303!